# Process killed on linux unexpectedly

Tags: linux, process, kill, sigkill

My process gets killed on linux server without manual intervention. I have verified the following scenarios.

- No manual intervention done to kill either by user or admin
- RAM and SWAP are not exhausted
- 'strace' gives me the message that "+++ killed by SIGKILL +++" - This makes me to assume that Kernel has killed the process.

The process occupies 16.5GB of virtual memory where the RAM is 16GB and the SWAP being 50GB.

Tasks: 393 total,   2 running, 387 sleeping,   4 stopped,   0 zombie

Cpu(s): 12.8%us,  0.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

Mem:     **16015M** total,     8700M used,     7315M free,      202M buffers

Swap:    **51199M** total,      150M used,    51048M free,     5906M cached

PID    USER      PR    NI  **VIRT**  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

31466  xyz        20   0   **16.4g** 1.3g 6704 R  100  8.3   0:16.99   *test**

Could you please tell me the other reasons for Kernel to kill the process..

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that [kernel out-of-memory (OOM) killer](http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/) killed your process. You need check `dmesg` output to see what was the exact reason for the kernel to kill your process.

Comment: Maxim, I have examined dmesg output while the process is being killed. But no info related to killing of process could be seen from it. Is the procedure I have followed is correct ?

Comment: @Sobhan Depending on the distribution, old kernel log messages may be archived, so you need to check those archives.

Comment: I couldn't observe any such messages in /var/log of the machine